# Complete path numbering of org-mode headlines and plain lists

Tags: org-mode

I would like to get the complete hierarchy numbers in the plain lists of org-mode

Instead of this:

```
1. something
   1. something
   2. something
      1. something
2. something
   1. something
   2. something
   3. something
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
1. something
1.1. something
1.2. something
1.2.1. something
2. something
2.1. something
2.2. something
2.3. something
```

And the same thing in headlines. Instead of this:

```
* chapter
** section A
** section B
*** subsection 
* chapter
** section A
** section B
```

this:

```
* 1. chapter
** 1.1. section A
** 1.2. section B
*** 1.2.1. subsection 
* 2. chapter
** 2.1. section A
** 2.2. section B
```

This helps me to see how many children a headline has and where I am.

EDIT:
Is it at least possible to get the table of contents with the complete numbering of the headlines (for easier navigating in the org document)?

New EDIT:
I mean a new buffer with just these lines (the items are empty):

```
* 1. chapter
** 1.1. section A
** 1.2. section B
*** 1.2.1. subsection 
* 2. chapter
** 2.1. section A
** 2.2. section B
```

Of course every line of the "new buffer" should be linked with the corresponding headline of the org document: So by clicking or typing "RETURN" I can go to the headline directly.

I know that by exporting to txt I can get the TOC but there aren't the links to the headlines. What I'm looking for (meanwhile) is a function that construct the toc with numbers and with links.

Comment: What you want doesn't exist (as far as I know).

Comment: Dan is right (afaik). You can only see the structure with full numbering after exporting to e.g. latex, odt, or text.

Comment: @rl1: not sure what you mean.  I don't think `org` does a table of contents in the `org` buffer.  Maybe you mean when you export it?

Comment: @Dan No, I mean before exporting. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a lightly tested approach to use overlays on the headings. This will work up to 9th level headings (one less zero than is in the counters).

```
(require 'cl)
(require 'dash)
(defun overlay-numbered-headings ()
  "Put numbered overlays on the headings."
  (interactive)
  (loop for (p lv) in (let ((counters (copy-list '(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)))
                (current-level 1)
                last-level)
            (mapcar (lambda (x)
                  (list (car x)
                    ;; trim trailing zeros
                    (let ((v (nth 1 x)))
                      (while (= 0 (car (last v)))
                        (setq v (butlast v)))
                      v)))
                (org-map-entries
                 (lambda ()
                   (let* ((hl (org-element-context))
                      (level (org-element-property :level hl)))
                     (setq last-level current-level
                       current-level level) 
                     (cond
                      ;; no level change or increase, increment level counter
                      ((or (= last-level current-level)
                       (> current-level last-level))
                       (incf (nth current-level counters)))

                      ;; decrease in level
                      (t
                       (loop for i from (+ 1 current-level) below (length counters)
                         do
                         (setf (nth i counters) 0))
                       (incf (nth current-level counters))))

                     (list (point) (-slice counters 1)))))))
    do
    (let ((ov (make-overlay p (+ 1 p))))
      (overlay-put ov 'display (concat (mapconcat 'number-to-string lv ".") ". "))
      (overlay-put ov 'numbered-heading t))))


(define-minor-mode numbered-org-mode
  "Minor mode to number org headings."
  :init-value nil
  (if numbered-org-mode 
      (overlay-numbered-headings)
    (ov-clear 'numbered-heading)))
```

Comment: Just "require"?  Actually, I'm not sure wich packages you mean (still an emacs beginner). 

With cl you mean: https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/cl-lib.html ? (there are other cl-* packages)
`dash` I've found by using `M-x list-packages`. 

 
Is `ov` the name abbreviation of some package - I couldn't find it by `M-x list-packages`.

Comment: I have edited the answer with the requires you need. ov is a package in Melpa, but this solution doesn't use any features from it; it uses builtin overlay functions.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I'm looking for. I can generate the numbers and remove them. _BUT_ It works only at the first time: `M-x overlay-numbered-headings` gives the correct numbering (let's say 1. 2. 3.) . `M-x remove-numbered-overlays` remove them as expected. But a second call of `M-x overlay-numbered-headings` gives a strange numbering (4. 5. 6.): It seems to save the old values (?)

Comment: sure enough. That must have to do with some kind of closure I guess. I added a line to make a copy of the counters list and also added a minor mode to make toggling it on and off easier.

Comment: Great! It's working and it's very easy to use (and for me it is important that  it doesn't change the document). 



I think in this version you have  forgotten the require commands (`cl` and `dash`).

Comment: Just one thing. Your function removes one star from every heading. So `* section` is transformed to `1. section`, and `** subsection` (for example) to `* 1.1. subsection.` Actually reducing the numbers of stars is better: You don't need them if you have the complete path with the numbers. One star would be enough for better distinguishing from plain lists.

Answer (score 5):

Org mode from version 9.3 includes the library `org-num`. Activating `org-num-mode` displays the outline numbers for headlines as overlays that updates automatically when editing. There are also customization options for excluding trees that are commented, have special tags, or have the `UNNUMBERED` property.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative implementation of the overlay solution provided in John Kitchin’s answer is to just use the standard functions from `org-export`.
I have wrapped this up in a small library here: https://gitlab.com/andersjohansson/org-outline-numbering

The core is this function (which serves as a direct replacement for Kitchin’s `overlay-numbered-headings`):

```
(require 'ox)
(require 'cl-lib)
(require 'ov)

(defun org-outline-numbering-overlay ()
  "Put numbered overlays on the headings."
  (interactive)
  (cl-loop for (p lv) in
           (let* ((info (org-combine-plists
                         (org-export--get-export-attributes)
                         (org-export--get-buffer-attributes)
                         (org-export-get-environment)
                         '(:section-numbers t)))                      
                  (tree (org-element-parse-buffer))
                  numberlist)
             (org-export--prune-tree tree info)
             (setq numberlist
                   (org-export--collect-headline-numbering tree info))
             (cl-loop for hl in numberlist
                      collect (cons
                               (org-element-property :begin (car hl))
                               (list (cdr hl)))))
           do
           (let ((ov (make-overlay p (+ (length lv) p))))
             (overlay-put ov 'display (concat (mapconcat 'number-to-string lv ".") ". "))
             (overlay-put ov 'numbered-heading t)
             (overlay-put ov 'face 'default))))
```