# Indexing subtrees

Tags: org-mode

Let's say I have the following structure

```
** fruit
*** handkerchief
**** hat
**** smoke
*** ticket
**** cinema
***** toad
```

It is now possible to think of the subtrees under `fruit` as indexed,
relatively to `fruit`, in the following manner:

- 1
- 1.1
- 1.2
- 2
- 2.1
- 2.11

How could I write a function that takes the ID of `fruit` as an argument
and returns the `fruit`-relative index of the current subtree?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
(defun my-index ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((all-hls (cl-loop for entry in
               (org-export--collect-headline-numbering (org-element-parse-buffer)
                                   (org-combine-plists
                                    (org-export--get-export-attributes)
                                    (org-export--get-buffer-attributes)
                                    (org-export-get-environment)
                                    '(:section-numbers t)))
               collect (cons (org-element-property :begin (car entry))
                     (cdr entry))))
     (reference-hl (save-excursion
             (org-open-link-from-string "[[*fruit]]")
             (cdr (assoc (org-element-property :begin (org-element-context)) all-hls))))
     (reference-depth (length reference-hl))
     (this-hl (cdr (assoc (org-element-property :begin (org-element-context)) all-hls))))
    (message
     (mapconcat 'number-to-string (nthcdr reference-depth this-hl) "."))))
```

It is adapted from code at [Complete path numbering of org-mode headlines and plain lists](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32396/complete-path-numbering-of-org-mode-headlines-and-plain-lists).